# Determinant of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

There will be $a_{1},...,a_{n}$ real numbers.
Lets define:

$
M =
\begin{vmatrix}
a_{1} & a_{1}^{2} & ... & a_{1}^{n-1} & 1+a_{1}^{n} \\
a_{2} & a_{2}^{2} & ... & a_{2}^{n-1} & 1+a_{2}^{n} \\
... &... &... &... &... \\
a_{n-1} & a_{n-1}^{2} & ... & a_{n-1}^{n-1} & 1+a_{n-1}^{n}\\
a_{n} & a_{n}^{2} & ... & a_{n}^{n-1} & 1+a_{n}^{n}
\end{vmatrix}
$
$
,M_{1} =
\begin{vmatrix}
a_{1} & a_{1}^{2} & ... & a_{1}^{n-1} & 1 \\
a_{2} & a_{2}^{2} & ... & a_{2}^{n-1} & 1 \\
... &... &... &... &... \\
a_{n-1} & a_{n-1}^{2} & ... & a_{n-1}^{n-1} & 1\\
a_{n} & a_{n}^{2} & ... & a_{n}^{n-1} & 1
\end{vmatrix}
$

Prove that if $M=0$ and $M_{1}\neq 0$ so $a_{1}\cdot ...\cdot a_{n}$ of $a_{1},...,a_{n}$ equals $1$ or $-1$.

I know that we should use this rule - If there are two matrix $A,B$ $nxn$, that the difference between them is the $i$ column so there is a matrix $C$ that her $i$-column is the sum of the A's and B's column and her other columns are like A's or B's. So - $detC=detA+detB$

Comment: @AlexR. I edited

Comment: Your last statement is not quite clear.

Comment: @Mambo I meant $M$ & $M_{1}$ are Determinants

Answer (score 1):

Instead, use $M,M_1$ as notation for the corresponding matrices. Notice that you can multiply the rows $i$ of $M_1$ by $a_i$, and after switching around columns you'll get back something that looks like $M-[1]$ where the bracketed part is a matrix of all zeros except for the right most column of all 1s. Using linearity on $|M|$, it follows that:

$$0=|M|=|M_1|+(-1)^n a_1\cdots a_n|M_1|,$$

which when rearranged give you the desired result, with the fact that $|M_1|\neq 0$.